# JPA EntityManager finder method returning other sub class object

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1

I am facing an issue with JPA EntityManager finder method. JPA entities are using inheritance structure as follows:

```
//Need to persist this table to database
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Table(name="Table1")
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PRIMARY_ID")
    private long id;
    private String field1;
    .......
}

//This table will NOT persist and has parameters only for Sub classs
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class MappedSuperClassEntity extends BaseEntity  {

      private String field2;
      private String field3;
      ........
    }

//This sub class is persisted and inherits fields form above class including Primary Key using TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy defined in BaseEntity
    @Entity
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    @Table(name="SubTable1")
    public class Sub1 extends MappedSuperClassEntity {
      private String field4;
      private String field5;
      ...............     
    }

//This sub class is persisted and inherits fields form above class including Primary Key using TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy defined in BaseEntity   
    @Entity
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    @Table(name="SubTable2")
    public class Sub2 extends MappedSuperClassEntity {
      private String field4;
      private String field5;
      ..............      
    }
```

As you can see, Sub1 and Sub2 are persistable entites and both of which extends MappedSuperClassEntity which is annotated with `@MappedSuperClass'. This class further inherits BaseEntity which has decribed TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy.

I enabled the hibernate stat collector and found that hibernate is storing sub class objects using key of Parent class. So in the above case it stores the data as follows for Sub1 finder in cache:

14:17:03,941 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.TransactionalCache] cache lookup: com.abc.BaseEntity#10
14:17:03,943 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.TransactionalCache] cache miss
14:17:03,948 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.TransactionalCache] caching: com.abc.BaseEntity#10

Next time if i do a find for Sub2 for same id (10), hibernate thinks it is in Cache as it uses Parent Class as key and returns the Sub1 object as follows:

14:27:54,574 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.TransactionalCache] cache lookup: com.abc.BaseEntity#10
14:27:54,575 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.TransactionalCache] cache hit

So this is happening when you run the finders for Sub1 and Sub2:

```
entityManager.find(Sub1.class, id);   //returns Sub1 object
entityManager.find(Sub2.class, id);   //returns Sub1 object (PROBLEM HERE).
```

Please help me to fix the issue (I do not want to clear cache in between these calls)

Comment: Post your mapping.

Comment: I have given the complete structure, please have a look and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a base entity when that doesn't make sense. When you inherit from a base entity, and not just from a mapped superclass, you're not just inheriting fields and methods. You're establishing an **is a** relationship.

An example where that would make sense is the following: Car and Bike both inherit a base entity Vehicle. In that case, a Car entity is a Vehicle entity. And a Bike entity is a Vehicle entity.

If a car has an ID 42, then a Bike may **not** also have the ID 42, because you would have two vehicles with the same ID. Imagine a Driver entity with a ManyToOne association with a vehicle (i.e. a driver drives a vehicle). If I store the ID 42 in the vehicle_id column of the driver table, this ID 42 must uniquely identify a vehicle. It could be a car, it could be a bike, and hibernate will look in both tables, but it can't be both at the same time.

You're violating this inheritance concept. BaseEntity should not be annotated with Entity. It should just be a MappedSuperclass, which just allows inheriting fields and methods, but doesn't establish this semantic **is a** association.

Comment: Thanks for the response and understand what you are trying to explain here. In my case I need to persist the BaseEntity class too when a persist is called on that object. How can I achieve that if I mark it as MappedSuperClass. If that cannot be done would this mean to get it working I need to ensure that I always persist a record in complete inheritance struction uniquely?